# logback.xml settings not respected

Tags: logback

When I launch a java app in Eclipse that uses Spring Boot, my logging settings are only respected up until `springDrivenXREApplication.run()` is invoked. Thereafter it reverts to some default settings.

Putting this in the VM args had no effect:

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/app/src/main/resources/logback.xml
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an omission in your build path. The easy way to work around it is to copy the logback.xml to the classpath root manually:

```
cp /path/to/app/src/main/resources/logback.xml /path/to/app/target/classes/
```